# How do I use throttle with .hover(); jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, throttling

I'm trying to find the most concise way to throttle a hover function with jQuery. There are many examples of this but they all seem to not work as intended. For example the use of `$.throttle` doesn't error but it stops the animation from working altogether. This is the code which I'm trying to throttle:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var $navTab = $('.nav-tab-parent');

  function moveNavTab(e) {
      TweenLite.to($navTab, 0.3, {
      css: {
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
      }
    });
  }

  $(window).on('mousemove', moveNavTab);

  $(".toggle-bars").hover( // this is the .hover() function I need to throttle.
    function() {
      $(".nav-tab-parent").animate({
        opacity: 1
      });
      $(".nav-tab-parent").delay(10).animate({
        width: "36px",
        easing: "swing"
      });
      $(".nav-tab").html("MENU");
      $(".nav-tab").delay(350).animate({
        opacity: 1
      });
    }, function() {
      $(".nav-tab").animate({
        opacity: 0
      });
      $(".nav-tab-parent").delay(150).animate({
        width: "0",
        opacity: 0,
        easing: "swing"
      });
    }
  );
});
```

I must be missing something here but can't figure it out. Any help in achieving this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What actually you are trying to achieve? To not to launch animation while its still running?

Comment: @t1m0n there is an animated text field that appears when hovering over certain links on the page, the problem is that if the user hovers and unhovers and then rehovers quick enough, it breaks the cycle of the animation. So for a seamless animation I need to throttle the hover function so that the animation can't flick between states

Comment: The trick I used to do is call `.stop()` before each animation. This is also explained in conjunction with hover in the jQuery docs.. so please read the docs here: [stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: Are you using GSAP tweenlite? I recall an animation "!while" function there but want to confirm.

Comment: @coll yeah it's the GSAP TweenMax library

Comment: @van are you open to changing the jquery to GSAP? hoverin, timescale(1); hoverout, timescale(0) https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Timeline/timeScale() , can provide complete answer if open to it

Comment: @coll of course! I would be open to this and that would be really helpful, one question - would the timescale() apply to just the hover itself or would it clip the animation on the way out?

Answer (score 1):

Changed to use entirely GSAP and relying on `.timescale()` see the [documentation](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Timeline/timeScale()) — didn't know the underlying structure so will need some configuring but the basis is there. [GSAP has a crazy deep documentation](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP) but should be familiar enough to jquery with object animations.

```js
var tl = gsap.timeline().timeScale(-1);
tl.fromTo(".nav-tab-parent", {
  autoAlpha: 0,
  duration: 1
}, {
  autoAlpha: 1,
  duration: 1
});
$(".toggle-bars").hover(function() {
  tl.timeScale(1);
}, function() {
  tl.timeScale(-1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.8.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-bars">.toggle-bars
  <div class="nav-tab-parent">.nav-tab-parent</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to achieve something like this. You could try to use `.stop()` method - it will stop current animation and after that you can run next one. Try to play with arguments to choose what best will suit your case.

```js
let $hover = $('.hover-box'),
  $target = $('.animated-box');

function show() {
  $target.stop(true, true).animate({
    opacity: 1,
  })
}

function hide() {
  $target.stop(true, true).animate({
    opacity: 0
  })
}

$hover.hover(show, hide)
```

```css
.hover-box,
.animated-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.hover-box {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.hover-box:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

.animated-box {
  opacity: 0;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='hover-box'>Hover</div>

<div class='animated-box'></div>
```